# How can I generate call graphs for Perl modules and scripts?

Tags: perl, aix, call-graph

I have a bunch of Perl scripts and Perl modules given to me by someone. I have a driver program that tests all these scripts and modules. I want to generate a call graph and see the flow.

Is there something available for Perl for doing this?
I'd like something like [pycallgraph](http://pycallgraph.slowchop.com/) (for python). I am running all this in AIX.

Answer (score 12):

Simon Cozens tells you how to do it in [Profiling Perl](http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2004/06/25/profiling.html) on [Perl.com](http://www.perl.com). He uses a combination of [Devel::DProf](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-DProf) and [GraphViz](http://search.cpan.org/dist/GraphViz).