# Creating call graph

Tags: go, call-graph

I am looking for a possibility to generate a call graph for Go projects. Something similar to [Doxygen's diagram functionality](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/diagrams.html) for C++ classes (with the option CALL_GRAPH=YES).

So far I found

http://saml.rilspace.org/profiling-and-creating-call-graphs-for-go-programs-with-go-tool-pprof

or
http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs

This samples the call stack of your program 100 times per second while the program is running and creates a graph useful for profiling. If your program spends most of its time in functions not relevant to you, I found this solution not very usefull.

Then there is this:

https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/go/callgraph/static

which from its description sounds like what I would need, but there seem to be no docs and I don't understand how to use it.

I also found

https://github.com/davecheney/graphpkg/blob/master/README.md

and
https://github.com/paetzke/go-dep-graph/blob/master/README.org

but they create only dependency graphs.

Comment: Updated link about go tool pprof (accidentally lost the .org domain, sorry): http://saml.rilspace.com/profiling-and-creating-call-graphs-for-go-programs-with-go-tool-pprof

Comment: See my answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/67692928/251947

Answer (score 19):

Take a look here:

- http://dave.cheney.net/2014/10/22/simple-profiling-package-moved-updated
- https://github.com/pkg/profile

```
func main() {
   defer profile.Start(profile.CPUProfile, profile.ProfilePath(".")).Stop()
   // Rest of program
}
```

Build and run your program as per normal. You'll see the profiling hook
mentioned:

```
2015/07/12 09:02:02 profile: cpu profiling enabled, cpu.pprof
```

Run your program (bench it, run through it, etc) to generate the profile during
runtime. Once you've hit what you want, quit and then generate the call-graph:

```
go tool pprof -pdf -output cgraph.pdf $YOURPROGBINARY cpu.pprof
```

You can also run `go tool pprof $YOURPROGBINARY cpu.pprof` to get an
interactive prompt where you can call `top10` or `web` to generate an svg. Type
`help` at the pprof prompt to get a list of commands.

e.g. - here's the CPU profile for a buffer pool implementation I wrote:

```
~/Desktop go tool pprof poolio cpu.pprof
Entering interactive mode (type "help" for commands)
(pprof) top5
24770ms of 35160ms total (70.45%)
Dropped 217 nodes (cum <= 175.80ms)
Showing top 5 nodes out of 74 (cum >= 650ms)
    flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
 12520ms 35.61% 35.61%    12520ms 35.61%  runtime.mach_semaphore_wait
  9300ms 26.45% 62.06%     9360ms 26.62%  syscall.Syscall
  1380ms  3.92% 65.98%     2120ms  6.03%  encoding/json.(*encodeState).string
  1030ms  2.93% 68.91%     1030ms  2.93%  runtime.kevent
   540ms  1.54% 70.45%      650ms  1.85%  runtime.mallocgc
```

And here's a quick way to generate a PNG from the prompt:

```
(pprof) png > graph.png
Generating report in graph.png
```

Which outputs this:

[image: callgraph-example-poolio]

Comment: One of my problems is that I am also interested in functions which are executed only once (during setup). Is there a way to increase the sampling rate of the tool, s.t. the probability increases that short running functions are also sampled?

Comment: The sampling rate is hardcoded in runtime/pprof.go:587 via runtime.SetCPUProfileRate(hz) with hz=100, i.e. 100 samples per second. If one calls runtime.SetCPUProfileRate(desiredSamplingRate) *before* calling profile.Start(), one can override this. Trying to set the sampling rate after calling profile.Start() will not work ("runtime: cannot set cpu profile rate until previous profile has finished.").

Comment: Still it does not solve my problem, since my program spends most of its time in http calls or waiting and the reason why I want the call graph is not for profiling but for understanding the logic of the code (not my own). I want to know how the separate components work together, i.e. which function calls which other function / the flow of the program.

Answer (score 17):

You were close with …`/x/tools/go/callgraph/static`. I'm pretty sure `go install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/callgraph` is what you want. Once installed run it without arguments to see it's full help/usage.

(In general, the things under …`/x/tools/` are somewhat reusable packages with command line front-ends living under …`/x/tools/cmd`, you can install them all with `go install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/...`, the literal `/...` matches all sub-packages).

E.g. running just `callgraph` produces usage output that starts with:

> **callgraph**: display the the call graph of a Go program.
>
> Usage:
>
> `callgraph [-algo=static|cha|rta|pta] [-test] [-format=...] <args>...`
>
> Flags:
>
> `-algo`      Specifies the call-graph construction algorithm, one of:
>
> ```
>         static      static calls only (unsound)
>         cha         Class Hierarchy Analysis
>         rta         Rapid Type Analysis
>         pta         inclusion-based Points-To Analysis
>
>        The algorithms are ordered by increasing precision in their
>        treatment of dynamic calls (and thus also computational cost).
>        RTA and PTA require a whole program (main or test), and
>        include only functions reachable from main.
> ```
>
> `-test`      Include the package's tests in the analysis.
>
> `-format`    Specifies the format in which each call graph edge is displayed.
>              One of:
>
> ```
>         digraph     output suitable for input to
>                     golang.org/x/tools/cmd/digraph.
>         graphviz    output in AT&T GraphViz (.dot) format.
> ```

It can produce arbitrary formatted output (using Go's template syntax) or graphviz or digraph output. The last is a tool you can install with `go install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/digraph` (and once again, full/help usage is seen by running it without arguments) and can answer queries about arbitrary directed graphs (including call graphs obviously).

Comment: Thanks! I experimented with callgraph using the different algo-flags and tried to produce a pdf using graphviz/dot or query the output of callgraph using digraph. Unfortunately, the output of callgraph contains mostly go libs and producing a pdf from the output of callgraph does not give anything usable. The query capabilities of digraph may turn out helpfull. The best solution for me would be, if I could filter out the go lib function calls - especially the deeply nested ones, for which my code is not even responsible. Maybe I can just do some postprocessing with callgraph's result.

Comment: There is another major obstacle which prevents me from using callgraph - it refuses to work, when I import ZeroMQ bindings (github.com/pebbe/zmq3). The first output is "cgo pkg-config not supported" and than lots of "undeclared name" errors from the zmq package, although they are declared in the package.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach, which does use [`golang.org/x/tools` `go/callgraph`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools@v0.1.0/go/callgraph) is the [**ofabry/go-callvis**](https://github.com/ofabry/go-callvis) project:
(Go 1.13+)

> The purpose of this tool is to provide developers with a visual overview of a Go program using data from call graph and its relations with packages and types.
>
> - support for Go modules!
> - focus specific package in the program
> - click on package to quickly switch the focus using interactive viewer
> - group functions by package and/or methods by type
> - filter packages to specific import path prefixes
> - ignore funcs from standard library
> - omit various types of function calls
>
> Example (based on this [Go code project](https://github.com/ofabry/go-callvis/tree/master/examples/main)):
>
> [image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ofabry/go-callvis/master/images/main.png]
>
> ### How it works
>
> It runs [**pointer analysis**](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/go/pointer) to construct the call graph of the program and uses the data to generate output in [dot format](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language), which can be rendered with Graphviz tools.
>
> To use the interactive view provided by a web server that serves SVG images of focused packages, you can simply run:
>
> ```
> go-callvis <target package>
> ```
>
> HTTP server is listening on http://localhost:7878/ by default, use option `-http="ADDR:PORT"` to change HTTP server address.

Answer (score 0):

I used golang callgraph recently, and I build a web tool with python + callgraph called CallingViewer here: https://github.com/fiefdx/CallingViewer , it maybe rough, but it work, the screenshot at below:
[screenshot of CallingViewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HXgX.png)

Comment: Looks interesting, will try it out later